# php server parse simple string using JSON to Android client

Tags: php, android, json

Hi i am quite new in Android client `php` server. I follow some tutorial for post and response variable by `JSON` but this reponse **error**. `Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`.

The `JSON` post is success but the response is error.

**Android code:**

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);           

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.1/databastest/login.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));        
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

// Create a JSON object from the request response
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

//Retrieve the data from the JSON object
resultLoging = jsonObject.getString("ResultArray");


}catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("ClientServerDemo", "Error:", e);
    exception = e;
}

return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean valid){
    //Update the UI
    Toast.makeText(mContext, resultLoging, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(exception != null){
        Log.i("Error",exception.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(mContext, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

**php code**

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO usersacc
(phone, password) VALUES('$pho', '$pass')");


        #Build the result array (Assign keys to the values) 
        $result_data = array( 
           'ResultArray' => 'success',
            ); 

        #Output the JSON data 
        echo json_encode($result_data);
```

The insert is successful but the result not done.

Comment: Try to print your "jsonObject" data, find out the data format.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this your code with this may work.Get the response from server as Object not as String.

```
Object result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString()); 
resultLoging = jsonObject.getString("ResultArray");
```

Comment: Try to print the "jsonObject" data, is that in json format?

Comment: Log.i("jsonformabc", jsonObject.toString());
i used this but no response??

Comment: use Log.i("result", result.toString()); and check the response. still its null the problem is in your server, server not returning the data, try the server script in browser and check the data is printing or not.